# Angle of Elevation (Depression) Between two 3D points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, kinematics, robotics

I have some eight points with defined coordinates in 3D space. These are from a straigth but bent and connected with matlab code as in Figure 1. [image]My challenge is that I need to compute the angle that exists between each consecutive 3D points in the bent line after folding the straight line to reach a defined target point. I have added Figure 1 to show the angles I am referring to. How can I calculate those angles by trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

I am indebted in this solution to @Nominal Animal that has made me the fundamental remark that using cross product couldn't do in all situations.

Let us recall the dot product formula:

$$\tag{1}\vec{W} \cdot \vec{W'}=\|\vec{W}\|\|\vec{W'}\|\cos(\theta) \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \cos(\theta) = \dfrac{\vec{W} \cdot \vec{W'}}{\|\vec{W}\|\|\vec{W'}\|}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $\vec{W}$ and $\vec{W'}$.

Here is the way one can proceed for finding the angles:

- Compute the consecutive differences between your $n=8$ consecutive points, in other terms, compute the components of the $n-1=7$ vectors $U_k:=\overrightarrow{P_kP_{k+1}}=P_{k+1}-P_k$ ($k=1,2,\cdots n-1$, differences component by component, of course).
- Compute the norms (lengths) of the $U_k$s.
- Compute the $n-2=6$ dot products $d_k=U_k \cdot (-U_{k+1})$ (minus sign is important). Then, using formula $(1)$:
- Compute the $a_k=\frac{d_k}{\|U_k\|.\|U_{k+1}\|}$ (the point meaning "ordinary product" between numbers.)
- Last step, the looked for angles are the $\cos^{-1}(a_k)$ of these numbers (refer to relationship $(1)$.)

**Recall**: the other formula for dot product: $\pmatrix{a\\b\\c} \cdot \pmatrix{d\\e\\f}=ad+be+cf.$

Comment: I would have suggested the same, except adding dot product,$$\left\lVert \vec{W}_1 \cdot \vec{W}_2 \right\rVert = \left\lVert \vec{W}_1 \right\rVert \left\lVert \vec{W}_2 \right\rVert \cos(\theta)$$The $\sin$ one is sufficient if the link can only pivot by -90° to +90° compared to "straight" (parallel to previous link); the $\cos$ one is sufficient if the link can only pivot by 0° to 180° (like a human knee joint, for example). To support any angle (-180° to +180°), one needs to use both.

Comment: You are right, it is the $\cos$ with the dot product, **instead of** the $\sin$ with cross product: in fact, after reflection, I dont think the OP needs  a $(-\pi,\pi)$ range. I modify my answer, mentionning your correction.

Comment: Thanks, let me remark the fact that the OP could require navigation in range of (-pi, pi).  Also, I am a little confused on the solution. You have mentioned 8 consecutive links and I guess these are V1-V8 and in fact, the start point is V0. V1' is the original position of V_1 on the straight line, and V2' for second joint with new point V2 and so on.  My concern is: will calculated value of theta (a_k) be the angle between original point Vk' and new point Vk or between consecutive points Vk-1 and Vk?  If the later is the case, hence there should be 9 consecutive points.  Please guide better

Comment: I think that in 3D space, and for such a problem, a $2\pi$ range is not relevant. I noted what you said about the range of values of $k$. I think that I have been sufficiently explicit about the fact that all operations were between consecutive points, and consecutive vectors. For the rest, typically it's up to the OP (who has been very silent...) to fill the residual gaps.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I couldn't understand your point raw so i decided to implement it in Matlab if I can see some points. Below is a given set of points and result of the algorithm you suggested. 

See Matlab Implementation Code and Result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrPrm.png
 
I should have 8 angles and not 7 as in the table! 
I will be glad you take a look and correct where I got it wrong. 
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrPrm.png

Answer (score 0):

It is by coordinate definition that point to point increments are reckoned. Especially so that the data given is discrete. Absolute frame of reference is used, since data points are given that way.

Between consecutive points

$$ x_2 - x_1 = \Delta x ;\; y_2 - y_1 =\Delta y ;\; z_2-z_1= \Delta z\; ;$$

for arbitrarily general/consecutive points

$$x_{i+1}-x_{i}=\Delta x\;; y_{i+1}-y_{i}=\Delta y\; ;z_{i+1}-z_{i}=\Delta z\;;$$

In spherical coordinate system ( $ \Delta \phi$ denoting elevation or depression ):

$$ \Delta r = \sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2} ; $$
$$\Delta \phi = \tan^{-1}{ \frac{\Delta z }{\Delta r}};$$

For *arctan* we need to use atan2 function to be sensitive to decide between quadrants.

While writing code one would like to importantly check

***Closed Loop conditions*** ( by setting the first and last points to be the same) of first difference sums should vanish, helps to detect any computational errors:

Cartesian coordinates

$$ \Delta\Sigma x=0\;,\Delta\Sigma y=0\;, \Delta\Sigma z=0\;$$

Spherical Coordinates

$$ \Delta\Sigma r=0\;, \Delta\Sigma \theta=0\;,\Delta\Sigma \phi=0\;$$
out of which only the last has been asked for here.