# How to calculate angle between two points in 3d space when the three axis changes

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-space-isomorphism, kinematics, robotics

I am working on a robot with multiple joints but just in 3DOF. I have resolved parameters of the first and second dof however in the third dof, there are 8 links. I have the base and target points of the links in this DOF, and I have been able to parameterize some arbitrary Cartesian coordinates for these links. The main objective is how to calculate the angles of joints holding these links.

For example, below are the coordinates for a given target point (8.6005,    0.4073,    5.3550), if the base of links in the 3rd DOF is (3.9228,    1.7883,    2.0000).
V0 =    [3.9228,     1.7883,     2.0000]
V1 =    [9.2359,     5.9971,     2.4194]
V2 =    [4.9271,    10.7107,     2.8388]
V3 =    [8.2702,    16.1519,     3.2581]
V4 =    [12.1939,    21.1906,     3.6775]
V5 =    [16.4524,    16.4285,     4.0619]
V6 =    [20.7109,    11.6664,     4.4462]
V7 =    [24.9693,     6.9042,     4.8306]
V8 =    [8.6005,    0.4073,     5.3550]
How can I compute thetas 1-8?
Note: the values of the three axes (X, Y, Z) in above V1-8 kept changing!

Comment: I'm afraid it is very difficult to understand what exactly you are asking. Perhaps you can draw a diagram of the first couple of links, including what you mean by *theta*? Also, if you do not mind, please drop the TLAs and instead write the full terms.

Comment: I understand DOF = Degrees Of Freedom. But what do you mean by saying "of the first and second dof however in the third dof, there are 8 links". "The first dof" How is possible to **rank** a dof ? I have done a lot of 3D geometry but I am sorry, the language you use is aimed at specialists of this domain that are very scarce on this forum. The less you can do, as @Nominal Animal said, is to provide us with a diagram.

Comment: @JeanMarie, you are correct. DOF means degree of freedom.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, JeanMarie, I had a similar post with image on [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010880/angle-of-elevation-depression-between-two-3d-points. Theta is the angle between each consecutive links in the image)

Comment: All right, I answer to (and in) your previous post.

Comment: Thanks, of all let me remark the fact that the OP could require navigation in range of (-pi, pi). Also, I am a little confused on the solution. You have mentioned 8 consecutive links and I guess these are V1-V8 and in fact, the start point is V0. V1' is the original position of V_1 on the straight line, and V2' for second joint with new point V2 and so on. My concern is: will calculated theta (a_k) be angle between original point Vk' and new point Vk or between consecutive points Vk-1 and Vk? If the later is the case, hence there should be 9 consecutive points. Please guide better